# what is nullptr error and how can i solve it?

Tags: c, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I want to make 'delete data at some position'.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int element;
typedef struct DListNode {
    element data;
    struct DListNode* llink;
    struct DListNode* rlink;
} DlistNode;

void init(DListNode* phead) {
    phead->llink = phead;
    phead->rlink = phead;
}
```

this is my print_dlist code

```
void print_dlist(DListNode* phead) {
    DListNode* p;
    for (p = phead->rlink; p != phead; p = p->rlink) {
        printf("<-| |%d| |->", p->data);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

and this is my insertlist code

```
void dinsert(DListNode* before, element data)

{
    DListNode* newnode = (DListNode*)malloc(sizeof(DListNode));
    newnode->data = data;
    newnode->llink = before;
    newnode->rlink = before->rlink;
    before->rlink->llink = newnode;
    before->rlink = newnode;
}
```

and this is the problem code

```
void DDLdelete(DListNode** head, int position) {
    DListNode* temp, * temp2 = *head;
    int k = 1;
    if (*head == NULL) {
        printf("List is empty");
        return;
    }
```

this part has error

```
    if (position == 1) {//delete at beginning
        *head = ( * head)->rlink;
        if (*head != NULL) {
            (* head)->rlink = NULL;
            free(temp);
            return;
        }
    }
```

i believe under this code do not have problem

```
    temp = *head;
    while ((k < position - 1) && temp->rlink != NULL) {
        temp = temp->rlink;
        k++;
    }
    if (temp->rlink == NULL) {// delete at the end
        temp2 = temp->llink;
        temp2->rlink = NULL;
        free(temp);
    }
    else {// delete in the middle
        temp2 = temp->llink;
        temp2->rlink = temp->rlink;
        temp->rlink->llink = temp2;
        free(temp);
    }
    return;

}
```

and this is main code

```
int main() {


DListNode* head = (DListNode*)malloc(sizeof(DListNode));
init(head);
printf("insert \n");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    
    dinsert(head, i);
    print_dlist(head);
}

printf("\n delete \n");

DDLdelete(&head, 3);
print_dlist(head);


free(head);
return 0;
}
```

this delete code has some problem but i don't know how i fix it. how can i solve this?

i want to print:

```
insert
<-| |0| |->
<-| |1| |-><-| |0| |->
<-| |2| |-><-| |1| |-><-| |0| |->
<-| |3| |-><-| |2| |-><-| |1| |-><-| |0| |->
<-| |4| |-><-| |3| |-><-| |2| |-><-| |1| |-><-| |0| |->
delete
<-| |4| |-><-| |2| |-><-| |1| |-><-| |0| |->
```

Unhandled exception dragged: read access violation.
p was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
is my error message at
printf("<-| |%d| |->", p->data);

Comment: Please [edit] and show a [mcve] instead of snippets of code that need to be stiched together.

Comment: In `DDLdelete`: `free(temp);`  : here `temp` has not yet been assigned a value. It's content is undetermined, it points nowhere.

Comment: i edit my question can you help me?

Comment: `*head = (* head)->rlink;` doesn't look right.  Shouldn't it be `head = head->rlink;` or `head = (*head).rlink`?  (assuming that your logic is correct)

Comment: Is the output you get the ouput you expect? When does the `nullptr error` occur? Please show the  __verbatim__ output you get including the error message. Show the output you get and the output you expect.

Comment: but if i modify (*head) to head, it makes error

Comment: `*head = (*head)->rlink` is okay, because it's a `Node **head`, but as Jabberwocky has already said, `temp` is unititialized; perhaps you meant `temp2`, which was initialized to `*head`. Also, you don't have to set `(*head)->rlink = NULL`, because if you have further nodes, they would be lost.

Comment: In general, your logic is not correct. If you remove the first node, check whether `*head == NULL`. If so, there are not nodes in the list; you're done. If there is a head, keep a temporary pointer to it, set `*head = (*haed)->rlink`, then free the temp pointer. You're done. If there was only one node, `*head` is `NULL` now. If not, it holds the new head.

Comment: i'm sorry but i can't understand your answer

Comment: you mean i delete this ? *head = (*haed)->rlink

Comment: No. Keep that, because that's what actually removes the first node. Remove the `if (*head != NULL)` clause after that and `free(temp2)` unconditionally and return.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps out:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int element;
typedef struct DListNode {
    element data;
    struct DListNode* llink;
    struct DListNode* rlink;
} DListNode;

void init(DListNode* phead, element data) {
    phead->llink = phead;
    phead->rlink = phead;
    phead->data = data;
}

void free_dlist(DListNode* head) {
    if (!head) {
        return;
    }
    DListNode* cur = head->rlink;
    while (cur != head) {
        DListNode* to_free = cur;
        cur = cur->rlink;
        free(to_free);
    }
    free(head);
}

void print_dlist(DListNode* phead) {
    if (!phead) {
        return;
    }
    printf("<-| |%d| |->", phead->data);
    for (DListNode* p = phead->rlink; p != phead; p = p->rlink) {
        printf("<-| |%d| |->", p->data);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void dinsert(DListNode* after, element data) {
    DListNode* newnode = malloc(sizeof(DListNode));
    if (!newnode) {
        exit(1);
    }
    newnode->data = data;
    newnode->rlink = after;
    newnode->llink = after->llink;
    after->llink->rlink = newnode;
    after->llink = newnode;
}

void DDLdelete(DListNode** head, int position) {
    DListNode *cur = *head;
    while (position) {
        // Seek desired node in the list
        if (cur == (*head)->llink) {
            // You decide what to do here.
            printf("attempted deletion out-of-bounds\n");
            return;
        }
        cur = cur->rlink;
        position--;
    }
    if (cur == *head) {
        if (cur->rlink == cur) {
            // Edge case detected: list has only one element, that being the head
            free(cur);
            *head = NULL;
            return;
        }
        *head = cur->rlink;
    }
    // Snip away cur from the list and free it
    cur->llink->rlink = cur->rlink;
    cur->rlink->llink = cur->llink;
    free(cur);
}

int main() {
    DListNode* head = malloc(sizeof(DListNode));
    if (!head) {
        exit(1);
    }
    init(head, 0);
    
    printf("insert \n");
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        dinsert(head, i);
        print_dlist(head);
    }
    
    
    printf("\n delete \n");
    
    DDLdelete(&head, 3);
    print_dlist(head);
    
    free_dlist(head);
    return 0;
}
```

`position` must not be negative in `DDLdelete()`!

Note: in this answer there were a minor things changed, like printing the head and its value in `print_dlist()`, `init()`'s function signature changed as part of making the list's head usefull, and `dinsert()` inserts a new `DListNode` after the one specified instead of before.

If you don't like those changes you can just use the new `DDLdelete()` and ignore everything else. However, since you are allowed to remove the list's head with my version of `DDLdelete()` and your original print function does not print the list's head, you can remove the head and not detect the difference with your original print function.

Or, if this does not meet your need at all, I will remove this answer. (I think that's the proper protocol in that scenario but I have no clue)